# How can I install Counter-Strike on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, counter-strike

Is it possible to install Counter-Strike on a MacBook Pro? If so, how?

Comment: A small clarification - are you talking about Counter-Strike or Counter-Strike: Source?

Answer (score 9):

You cannot install the original [Counter-Strike 1.6](http://store.steampowered.com/app/10/) on Mac without Windows emulation software. You can however install [Counter-Strike: Source](http://store.steampowered.com/app/240/), that's the revamped CS that has been ported to [Source engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_%28game_engine%29) (the same one as used in Half-Life 2).
Requirements are:

> Minimum: OS X version Leopard 10.5.8,
>   Snow Leopard 10.6.3, 1GB RAM, NVIDIA
>   GeForce 8 or higher, or ATI X1600 or
>   higher, Mouse, Keyboard, Internet
>   Connection

Update: As of 2015, I'd recommend newer [Counter-Strike: Global Offensive](http://store.steampowered.com/app/730). It supports Windows, OSX and Linux users on same servers.

Comment: *"Will this update (that we have to buy for $19.99) also work if other players are on windows, and you are on Mac?" — First of all, it's not _update_, it's a remake.  And yes, as long as you all playing same game (all CS:Source or all newer CS:Global Offensive).  For it's purposes Windows, OSX and Linux are considered same platform — PC. They use same servers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Cider port for this. Find any game with cider and then simply put windows cs1.6 files in it. Google and you will find correct steps in youtube. like this one.

Comment: could you add those website/blog links to your post? It would make your post alot more useful.

Comment: Sure, My bad, I will add links.

Comment: This video has been removed. It would be helpful if you could add a couple of points to make mac port work on cider otherwise this dead link makes this answer useless.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your system can handle it, you can install it off of steam.

The info is found here: http://store.steampowered.com/css

Answer (score 1):

Try darwine or wineBottler. They don't need a full Windows OS since they utilize Wine to run EXEs. You will still need CS though.

Answer (score 1):

CS : Source and CS : Global Offensive are available for Mac.

Otherwise you can enjoy CS : 1.6 through Windows BootCamp provided with Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is not about the operating system, which is by default MacOS X, I suppose you could install Boot Camp and try running the game on a Windows OS.